Instagram Graph API: possible to find usernames that used a specific hashtag?
We want to use the Instagram Graph API to get a list of public accounts that have used a specific tag recently (or a @). I already set the app up but before I am going to dive more deeply, I want to ask whether this is possible. Because the last post I read about it (in 2020) it wasn't possible due to privacy, but the lines that were quoted, aren't in the recent manual so I am not sure whether it is still applicable. I can't find another recent answer about it.
Does someone knows this? Thank you so much!
Post I mentioned Facebook Instagram Graph Api Get Tags with username
The recent manual: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/hashtag-search
I already googled it to try to find the answer
